# Retrieve information from database with PHP Classes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get information from my table using PHP classes, but it's not working

Please note that I'm aware I'm using `mysql_*` functions.

**Call on php page**

```
print $User->getCredits();
```

**Class**

```
require 'dbconfig.php';

class User {

    public function getCredits($uid)
    {
        echo 'asda';
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT credits FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_object($rs);
        return $row->credits;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Also, don't use mysql_* functions, use PDO.

Comment: @Jimbo, "before the comments Im aware im using mysql_*"

Comment: @Jimbo there is no objective reason to just use PDO everywhere, as it has a different interface. mysqli_* would be the correct replacement, as it has the same interface, is newer, and might yield better performance, depending on configuration (mysqlnd enabled or not etc)

Comment: You forgot to make a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. your class isn't being instantiated, and
2. you're not passing your `$uid` to the `getCredits()` method.

Leaving your Class definition as-is, you could do this:

**Call on php page**

```
$uid = 1;
$user = new User();
print $user->getCredits($uid);
```

---

However, I suggest you redesign your class to instantiate it with the user id in the constructor, and then your function should use the local user id param in the query, rather than requiring the uid at the method level.  Try this:

**Call on php page**

```
$uid = 1;
$user = new User($uid);
print $user->getCredits();
```

**Class**

```
require 'dbconfig.php';

class User {

    private $_uid;

    public function __construct($uid) {
        $this->_uid = $uid;
    }

    public function getCredits()
    {
        echo 'asda';
        $sql = "SELECT `credits` 
                FROM `users` 
                WHERE `oauth_uid` = '{$this->_uid}'";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
        return $row->credits;
    }

}
```

Comment: Although correct, a php class doesn't need an explicit constructor. On the other hand, it's probably more oo to do it this way. A matter of taste, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
have you created object of class `"User"` like this:

$User = new User();
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you're calling a member function without an instance of the class and also haven't passed a user id:

> print $User->getCredits();

Unless you have a variable $User with the same name as the class (a little confusing?). Is that the problem you're seeing? Also you're missing the function parameter `uid`

If you defined it as a static function you could then do `User::getCredits($uid)`. Either that or create an instance of the class... `$thisUser = new User(...); $thisUser->getCredits(...)`.

Comment: I'd try 
    print_r($row); 
from within the function first.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Insert code her to connect to db (mysql_connect / mysql_pconnect if you use the mysql -family ; but you should really switch to be using mysqli_*, which is mostly the same, but it's newer and might use mysqlnd php native driver for better performance)
$user = new User();
echo $user->getCredits();
```

Also you should add error checking (mysql_error()) and escape $uid (if it can only be int, you might use intval, but a genereic solution would be to use mysql_real_escape_string)

if you use backticks, you should use them consistently, e.g:

```
"SELECT `credits` FROM `users` WHERE `oauth_uid` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($uid) . '"
```